# Virtuoso R2RML rr:IRI generating

Tags: mapping, rdf, virtuoso, r2rml

I have a problem with generating `rr:termType` `rr:IRI` in Virtuoso. I don't know if am I doing it wrong but I followed the W3C specification.

My mapping looks like this. When I generate triples with `CONSTRUCT` statement I still get `"URL"` but not `IRI => <url>` (`OWNER_LINK` and `BRAND_LINK` columns).  Is it something Virtuoso doesn't support or am I coding it the wrong way?

```
DB.DBA.TTLP 
   (  '
        @prefix    rr:  <http://www.w3.org/ns/r2rml#>                                .
        @prefix  foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>                                 .
        @prefix    gr:  <http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#>                          .
        @prefix     s:  <http://schema.org/>                                         .
        @prefix   pod:  <http://linked.opendata.cz/ontology/product-open-data.org#>  .

        <#TriplesMap3>
           a                 rr:TriplesMap  ;
           rr:logicalTable 
              [
                 rr:tableSchema "POD"  ;
                 rr:tableOwner  "DBA"  ;
                 rr:tableName   "BRAND_OWNER_BSIN"
              ];
           rr:subjectMap 
              [ 
                 rr:template  "http://linked.opendata.cz/resource/brand-owner-bsin/{BSIN}"  ;
                 rr:class     gr:BusinessEntity                                             ;
                 rr:graph     <http://linked.opendata.cz/resource/dataset/product-open-data.org/2014-01-01>
              ];
        rr:predicateObjectMap 
              [
                 rr:predicate gr:hasBrand  ;
                 rr:objectMap 
                    [
                       rr:parentTriplesMap <#TriplesMap4>  ;
                       rr:joinCondition 
                          [
                             rr:child "OWNER_CD"   ;
                             rr:parent "OWNER_CD"  ;
              ];    ];    ];
        .


        <#TriplesMap4>
           a                rr:TriplesMap  ;
           rr:logicalTable 
              [
                 rr:tableSchema  "POD"          ;
                 rr:tableOwner   "DBA"          ;
                 rr:tableName    "BRAND_OWNER"
              ];
           rr:subjectMap 
              [ 
                 rr:template  "http://linked.opendata.cz/resource/brand-owner/{OWNER_CD}"  ;
                 rr:class     gr:BusinessEntity                                            ;
                 rr:graph     <http://linked.opendata.cz/resource/dataset/product-open-data.org/2014-01-01>
              ];

        rr:predicateObjectMap 
           [
              rr:predicate  gr:legalName  ;
              rr:objectMap
                 [ rr:column  "OWNER_NM" ];
           ];
        rr:predicateObjectMap 
           [
              rr:predicate  s:url  ;
              rr:objectMap
                 [
                    rr:termType  rr:IRI        ; 
                    rr:column    {OWNER_LINK}  ;
           ];    ];
        rr:predicateObjectMap 
           [
              rr:predicate  gr:hasBrand  ;
              rr:objectMap
                 [
                    rr:parentTriplesMap  <#TriplesMap3>  ;
                    rr:joinCondition 
                       [
                          rr:child   "OWNER_CD"   ;
                          rr:parent  "OWNER_CD"  ;
           ];   ];     ];
        .

        <#TriplesMap2>
           a                rr:TriplesMap;    
           rr:logicalTable 
              [
                 rr:tableSchema "POD"; 
                 rr:tableOwner  "DBA"; 
                 rr:tableName   "BRAND_TYPE" 
              ];
           rr:subjectMap 
              [ 
                 rr:template  "http://linked.opendata.cz/resource/brand-type/{BRAND_TYPE_CD}"  ;
                 rr:class     gr:BusinessEntityType                                            ;
                 rr:graph     <http://linked.opendata.cz/resource/dataset/product-open-data.org/2014-01-01>
              ];
           rr:predicateObjectMap 
              [
                 rr:predicate  gr:name  ;
                 rr:objectMap
                    [ rr:column  "BRAND_TYPE_NM" ];
              ];
        .


        <#TriplesMap1>
           a                rr:TriplesMap;    
           rr:logicalTable 
              [
                 rr:tableSchema "POD"   ; 
                 rr:tableOwner  "DBA"   ; 
                 rr:tableName   "BRAND" 
              ];
           rr:subjectMap 
              [ 
                 rr:template  "http://linked.opendata.cz/resource/brand/{BSIN}"  ;
                 rr:class     gr:Brand                                           ;
                 rr:graph     <http://linked.opendata.cz/resource/dataset/product-open-data.org/2014-01-01>
              ];
           rr:predicateObjectMap 
              [
                 rr:predicate  pod:bsin               ;
                 rr:objectMap  [ rr:column  "BSIN" ]  ;
              ];   
           rr:predicateObjectMap
              [
                 rr:predicate  gr:name                    ;
                 rr:objectMap  [ rr:column  "BRAND_NM" ]  ;
              ];
           rr:predicateObjectMap 
              [
                 rr:predicate  s:url  ;
                 rr:objectMap
                    [
                       rr:termType  rr:IRI        ; 
                       rr:column    "BRAND_LINK"  ;
              ];    ];

           rr:predicateObjectMap 
              [
                 rr:predicate  gr:BusinessEntityType  ;
                 rr:objectMap 
                    [
                       rr:parentTriplesMap  <#TriplesMap2>  ;
                       rr:joinCondition 
                          [
                             rr:child "BRAND_TYPE_CD"    ;
                             rr:parent "BRAND_TYPE_CD"   ;
              ];    ];    ];
        .
      ', 
      'http://product-open-data.org/temp', 
      'http://product-open-data.org/temp' 
   );

exec ( 'sparql ' || DB.DBA.R2RML_MAKE_QM_FROM_G ('http://product-open-data.org/temp') );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out my code was wrong it should be like this

```
 rr:predicateObjectMap 
    [
       rr:predicateMap
          [
             rr:constant  s:url 
          ]; 
       rr:objectMap 
          [ 
             rr:termType  rr:IRI          ; 
             rr:template  "{BRAND_LINK}"  ;
          ];

     ];.
```

and it's working

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear — are you saying the R2RML mapping is loading successfully, but when running a SPARQL `CONSTRUCT` query, the `rr:termType  rr:IRI` mapping is not being displayed in the result set?

[As the docs indicate](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtR2RML#Known%20Limitations), only `rr:sqlQuery` is not currently supported ...

Comment: Yes I am not getting any result set do you know what am I doing wrong? I am really despread when working with Virtuoso