# Virtuoso R2RML rr:IRI generating as Literal

Tags: mapping, virtuoso, r2rml

I have a problem when generating `rr:termType` `rr:IRI` in Virtuoso.

When I run the mapping, the result is a Literal instead an IRI.

Is this something Virtuoso doesn't support?

Comment: We need more information about how, where, and when you're encountering this issue. It sounds like a bug somewhere -- whether in your own code, Virtuoso, or some other element of your deployment. You may get faster answers via [Virtuoso-users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users) or [Virtuoso support forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/).

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821813/virtuoso-r2rml-rriri-generating